# Thumbnail representation of an activity

Tags: android

I want a thumbnail representation of the top activity. As `ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.thumbnail` always returns null according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html#thumbnail). So is there any other way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

1. Get a `Bitmap` screenshot of the topmost `Activity`'s view
   (`android.R.id.content`) using the drawing cache.
2. Scale activity screenshot to desired thumbnail size.

You should have access to the `Window` of course.

```
public Bitmap getScreenThumbnail(int width, int height) {

    // grab the window view
    View windowView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    // grab the topmost view
    View screenView = windowView.getRootView();

    // fetch view as a bitmap
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap screenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    // resize to desired thumbnail size
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(screenBitmap, width, height, false);
}
```

you can, of course, skip the resizing part and return the full `screenBitmap` instead.